# Computer not detecting keyboard or mouse

Tags: windows-7, setup, hardware-detection

I’ve been trying to solve this for two months now, basically the computer that’s broken had windows 10 on it previously and I started getting a black screen within 5 minutes of log in. I couldn’t even open a windows installer for a format or anything, so I used another computer to format the hard disk. There was no problems up to this point.

When I plug in the hard disk and put in the windows 7 installer disk  for windows 7, I can’t download it as my keyboard or mouse aren’t being detected or anything. They both light up but neither respond (when pressing numlock on keyboard the led doesn’t light up). I’ve tried 3 different keyboards, 2 different mice and still nothing. And no, I can’t even get into bios or anything like that. I’ve also tried putting it into usb 2.0 ports and replugging them in whilst I’m in the setup, as well as replacing the battery. I’ve had this problem for 2 months now.

Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-78LMT-USB3.

Answer (score 0):

You can test if the keyboard is working in Windows safe mode, You can access it pressing F8 when the computing is starting or reset. At that point the direction arrows on keyboard have to work, otherwise the physical Ports on the mother Board are damage, to test if they are damage or not is better to review computer BIOS, basic input output system to realize if Ports are identity on motherboard. Additionally the peripherials can be damage as a hardware so is better to replace them or add the right user drivers.
The following file have useful information about it: 
https://www.digitalcitizen.life/what-safe-mode-how-boot-safe-mode